# Delete record in Aerospike?

Tags: aerospike

I'm tuning Aerospike, after I use `Recipe for an SSD Storage Engine` with this config:

```
namespace test {
        replication-factor 2
        memory-size 4G
        default-ttl 30d # 30 days, use 0 to never expire/evict.

        #storage-engine memory
        storage-engine device {     # Configure the storage-engine to use persistence
        device /dev/vdb    # raw device. Maximum size is 2 TiB
        # device /dev/<device>  # (optional) another raw device.
        write-block-size 128K   # adjust block size to make it efficient for SSDs.
    }
}
```

After run the benchmarks first time,my SSD is completely full

```
quanlm@quanlm2:/mnt/device$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           395M  3.1M  392M   1% /run
/dev/vda1        60G  2.8G   54G   5% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vdb         64Z   64Z   59G 100% /mnt/device
tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1000
```

So is there anyway to delete the data in my SSD (/dev/vdb) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should not be mounting any file system on the device that Aerospike is configured to use. Aerospike manages its storage directly. The file system metadata will corrupt Aerospike storage.

In storage engine device configuration Aerospike will use the entire device irrespective of how much data you actually inserted. If you do not want to give entire device you can create raw partition on the device (without any file system) and configure the raw partition as device in Aerospike.

To see how much of the device is being used, you should be looking Aerospike stats. To wipe the device you can either use the `dd` command or the more time efficient `blkdiscard`.